# codeigniter - best practice library with many classes

Tags: php, inheritance, codeigniter, driver, libraries

I'm building a library for our CodeIgniter app, but it requires many classes (currently I'm at 12).

Is there a best practice for packaging these many clients into one library. So I can just make one call to load it. i.e:

```
$this->load->library('soaplibrary');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it simply a case of putting all the classes concerned into separate files, in a folder, then using $this->CI->load->library('myfolder/myclass') for every class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Summer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971365/codeigniter-best-practice-library-with-many-classes/4971887#4971887), they have handled this situation somewhat elegantly in CI 2.0 with the concept of Drivers.

With a Driver, you actually create a subdirectory within your 'libraries' directory that contains your 'super' class, and another directory for 'child' classes.  Better visual representation of the structure...

[image]

This was taken from [Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_drivers.html).

and once you have constructed your library, [here is the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/drivers.html) on how to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working on a site that's using ver 1.7. But should we upgrade then I can see that this is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 4):

In CI 2.0, there are drivers to handle this situation.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter 3.1.9 **when you load a library file, all classes in this file are included into code**.

Let's say in soaplibrary.php you have

```
class SoapLibrary {
   public function someMethod(...

class Test {
   public function anotherMethod(...
```

In your controller you can do:

```
$this->load->library('soaplibrary');

//now on you can do
$this->soaplibrary->someMethod();

//but also
$test = new Test();
$test->anotherMethod();
```

CodeIgniter **attempts to call the constructor of class `SoapLibrary`, hence a class with that name must be in there**.